# Find work given the force and displacement vectors

Tags: vectors

An airplane has performed an emergency landing and stops over a line of train tracks outside of Super City. Unfortunately, there is an incoming train, and while the train conductor has applied the brakes, the train will not decelerate in time to prevent a crash. Fortunately, Super Protector monitors the city, and his wristwatch informs him a plane at position (20m,10m,−5m) relative to Headquarters is in danger. Swiftly our hero swoops down and moves the plane to the coordinates (10m,30m,0) with a constant force of =(−15+30+17)kN. How much work is done by Super Protector?

I can't understand how do you go about to solve work because I have 3 dimensions. However, I am familiar with one dimension, W = D x F. Can someone help solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: In more than one dimension, $$ \ W \ = \ \overrightarrow{F} \ · \ \overrightarrow{\Delta x} \ \ , $$ using the dot product of the force vector with the _displacement_ (change in position) vector.